# C++ exception string displayed as garbage on Mac OS with Xcode and CLion

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++. I tried the following code on my MBP, macOS 10.14.6, Xcode 11.0.

```
include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;

void errthrow();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    try {
        errthrow();
    } catch (const char* pEx) {
        cerr << pEx << endl;
    }
}

void errthrow()
{
    char message[10] {"Exception"};
    throw message;
}
```

Instead of getting string "Exception" in the terminal, text "0\365\277\357\376" was outputted.

Compiled with CLion, the output is something like this: `'���

The code works fine on Windows 10, VS 2019.

Comment: As soon as errthrow is done, any non-dynamically allocated objects in it are automatically destroyed, that includes the message you are trying to throw. Effectively, what you are doing is 'undefined behaviour"

Comment: If you must throw arbitrary objects, throw a `std::string` instead.

Comment: Your variable message is allocated on stack. Every function called has its own stack frame and local variables in it. When you throw the compiler unwinds stack. That means that for all the local variables the destructor is called and the memory is deallocated. So when you throw your variable, before it reaches the catch statement, its memory is being deallocated and stack fram is being destroyed thats why you get a garbage value.

Comment: One nasty manifestation of undefined behaviour is the appearance of working fine.

Comment: I see, thanks guys.

Comment: @Botje Bad idea. I had to deal with a code that threw strings instead of exceptions. The author of the code apparently meant for the code to print an informative error message about a file being missing, but instead it printed "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'".

Comment: @jjramsey well, you're supposed to catch them at the top level at least...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.  This is a very subtle issue that really only applies to arrays.  When you do

```
char message[10] {"Exception"};
```

`message` is local to the function.  When you throw it, instead of copying the array, what happens is the array decays into a pointer, and it is the pointer that gets copied.  Because of this you are left with a pointer to `message` but `message` no longer exists after you exit the function.

If you need to throw a c-string, then the correct method if

```
throw "message to throw";
```

This works because `"message to throw"` is implcitly `static` and because of that it will live for the life of the program.  When you catch the pointer, the pointer still refers to a valid object unlike when you returned it from an array.